# Im having a little trouble with a toggle button on in my code

Tags: javascript, toggle, innerhtml

I don't know why the innerHTML isnt generating new text with my function.
Nothing changes even though jsfiddle tells me the syntax is correct. In short I want the words to repopulate the div. Right now nothing changes and the div is stuck with static text.

```
var btn = byId("tog");

btn.onclick = function() {
    var statusDiv = byId('status');
    var status = statusDiv.className;
    if (status == 'inactive') {
        statusDiv.className = 'active';
        byId("status").innerHTML = active;
    }
    else {
        statusDiv.className = 'inactive';
        byId("status").innerHTML = inactive;
    }
};
```

Comment: what is active and inactive? Do you have those variables defined or are they supposed to be strings? Why are you looking up the status element again when you already have it in statusDiv?

Comment: I want to make the <div id="status"> content change with innerHTML </div>

Comment: so what is `.innerHTML = inactive;` that inactive? Did you actually want `.innerHTML = "inactive";` Notice the quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's several mistakes in your code.  If you want to grab an ID, you'll have to use `document.getElementById('nameOfId')`.  Also when declaring a name to a class, you'll want to pass in a "string", otherwise you'll receive a syntax error expecting a variable.

**Here's your code rewritten:**

```
var btn = document.getElementById("tog");

btn.onclick = function() {
    var statusDiv = document.getElementById('status');
    var status = statusDiv.innerHTML;

    if (status === 'inactive') {
        statusDiv.className = 'active';
        statusDiv.innerHTML = 'active';
    } else {
        statusDiv.className = 'inactive';
        statusDiv.innerHTML = 'inactive';
    }
};
```

**Here's the working fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/fB6Cr/